# python string to json conversion

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a python script below which loads a yaml file. Arguments are passed in as a list so I can loop through them to add values to the dictionary. The code below adds the parameters but the json is not properly formatted as displayed in the current and desired json result. Any help in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks.

YAML File

```
  policies:
  - name: ec2age
    resource: ec2
    filters:      
      - State.Name: running
      - "tag:ResourceCreatedBy": present
      - and:
        - type: instance-age
          days: 30
          op: ge
```

Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import argparse
import json
import yaml

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-y", "--yaml_file", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-b", "--business_unit", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-p", "--platform", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-c", "--client", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.yaml_file, 'r') as stream:
    data = yaml.load(stream)

inner_dict = [args.business_unit, args.platform, args.client]

for item in list(inner_dict):
    data['policies'][0]['filters'][0]['tag:BUSINESS_UNIT'] = args.business_unit
    data['policies'][0]['filters'][1]['tag:PLATFORM'] = args.platform

print json.dumps(data)
```

Current Result:

```
{
"policies": [
    {
    "resource": "ec2",
    "name": "ec2age",
    "filters": [
        {
        "tag:BUSINESS_UNIT": "TEST_FLITE",
        "State.Name": "running"
        },
        {
        "tag:ResourceCreatedBy": "present"
        },
        {
        "and": [
            {
            "type": "instance-age",
            "days": 30,
            "op": "ge"
            }
        ]
        }
    ]
    }
]
}
```

Desired Result:

```
{
"policies": [
    {
    "resource": "ec2",
    "name": "ec2age",
    "filters": [
        {
        "tag:BUSINESS_UNIT": "TEST_FLITE"
        },
        {
        "tag:PLATFORM": "Android"
        },
        {            
        "State.Name": "running"
        },
        {
        "tag:ResourceCreatedBy": "present"
        },
        {
        "and": [
            {
            "type": "instance-age",
            "days": 30,
            "op": "ge"
            }
        ]
        }
    ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: It can be isssue with YAML, without looking at YAML it seems hard to tell.
You can verify tabs in your YAML, have you verified by printing dict/data itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code,

```
inner_dict = [args.business_unit, args.platform, args.client]

for item in list(inner_dict):
    """
      following line appends adds key to 0'th dict which is 
     {
    "tag:BUSINESS_UNIT": "TEST_FLITE",
    "State.Name": "running"
    }
    """
    data['policies'][0]['filters'][0]['tag:BUSINESS_UNIT'] = args.business_unit
    data['policies'][0]['filters'][1]['tag:PLATFORM'] = args.platform
```

You could do something like this,

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import argparse
import json
import yaml

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-y", "--yaml_file", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-b", "--business_unit", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-p", "--platform", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-c", "--client", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.yaml_file, 'r') as stream:
    data = yaml.load(stream)


inner_list = [{"tag:BUSINESS_UNIT" : args.business_unit},
              {"tag:PLATFORM" : args.platform},
              # {"tag:CLIENT" : args.client} #if needed
             ]

for i, item in enumerate(inner_list):
    data['policies'][0]['filters'].insert(i, item)

print(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Good idea with `insert`! However the OP didn't mention anything about `{"tag:PLATFORM" : args.client}`. But he/she should decide how to call that key, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code:

```
inner_dict = [args.business_unit, args.platform, args.client]

for item in list(inner_dict):
    data['policies'][0]['filters'][0]['tag:BUSINESS_UNIT'] = args.business_unit
    data['policies'][0]['filters'][1]['tag:PLATFORM'] = args.platform
```

doesn't really make a lot of sense. First, `inner_dict` is already a list. There is no reason why would we convert it to list again - `list(inner_dict)`.

Second, in the loop you iterate 3 times, once for every item in the list, and repeat the same statements in every iteration step. You don't use the `item` in those statements.

From here, without knowing the structure of the YAML file, is hard to provide a solution, but you should look for the above mentioned lines. I'd try without loop, just execute:

```
data['policies'][0]['filters'].append({'tag:BUSINESS_UNIT': args.business_unit})
data['policies'][0]['filters'].append({'tag:PLATFORM': args.platform})
```

EDIT: after you added the YAML file content I can give you a further explanation.
When you call `data['policies'][0]['filters']` you call this part:

```
[
    {            
        "State.Name": "running"
    },
    {
        "tag:ResourceCreatedBy": "present"
    },
    {
        "and": [
            {
                "type": "instance-age",
                "days": 30,
                "op": "ge"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Consequently `data['policies'][0]['filters'][0]` will return:

```
{            
    "State.Name": "running"
}
```

and `data['policies'][0]['filters'][0]['tag:BUSINESS_UNIT'] = args.business_unit` will add new key:value pair to that dict:

```
{            
    "State.Name": "running",
    "tag:BUSINESS_UNIT": "TEST_FLITE"
}
```

The loop doesn't help, it just does the same in every iteration step.

My proposal will append the needed key:value pairs as dictionaries to the end of the list. If the order really matters, then you have to shift the list. Take a look at the module [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added the yaml file content.